# Редактировать файл refind.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, config

Есть проблемы с rEFInd и гугл посоветовал в refind.conf прописывать параметр ядра "pci=nocrs" в строке "options", но я так и не понял в какой именно строке и как (Мне нужно добавить этот параметр или заменить предыдущий, если добавить, то через запятую или пробел? [Вот код из этого файла на pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/6LfeC1Ky)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Всем спасибо за помощь! 
Прописал в терминале команду

> mkrlconf

Далее задал в файле **refind_linux.conf** в конце строки

```
"Boot with standard options" "ro root=UUID=x-x-x-x-x"
```

параметр **pci=nocrs**, в итоге строка стала выглядеть вот так:

```
"Boot with standard options" "ro root=UUID=x-x-x-x-x pci=nocrs"
```

Теперь всё отлично работает!